# Two way receive port without Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009

Is it possible to create a two way receive port of type Submit without the use of Orchestration.

i.e., I want to submit a message to the message-box database and get the same exact message back to my C# program.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in Advance,

Danie

Answer (score 1):

Submit adapter is one way only I'm afraid. Why do you need the exact same message back?

Comment: Don't know why, but my client needs this to be done.. I tried my best to google. Am entirely new to biztalk. If you know any valuable resource (ebook) or blog to learn complete beiztalk ,please refer me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Create an endpoint in WCF or something similar which exposes the two way contract you require. Then call the submit adapter in code as outlined here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3125